# How to submit curl command to check status data from website?

Tags: scripting, curl

I would like to check status of case in the website below:

https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do

I can enter case number `MSC2190654545` and it gives status.

I have tried the options below but I don't get any status like I do when I try it using the browser

```
curl --data 'appReceiptNum=MSC2190655165' https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard/CaseStatus.do 

curl --data "appReceiptNum=MSC2190655165" --data "initCaseSearch=CHECK STATUS" https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard/CaseStatus.do

curl --data "appReceiptNum=MSC2190655165" --data "initCaseSearch=CHECK STATUS&submit" https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard/CaseStatus.do
```

Can someone please help with the correct command?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add more details to your question. Do you get an error message? If so, which? If not, in what way does the output differ from your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl 'https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/mycasestatus.do' --data-raw 'changeLocale=&completedActionsCurrentPage=0&upcomingActionsCurrentPage=0&appReceiptNum=MSC2190654545&caseStatusSearchBtn=CHECK+STATUS'   --compressed
```

Comment: Would you like to [edit] and explain your answer..?